# Print last <td> in beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, html-parsing

I have to read from a complex HTML document where a table does not have an ID and each table has undefined number of tr tags. I want to print the text in the td of the last `<tr>` tag. I could not find anything that prints the last child while parsing the tree.

I want to print 4,4.1,4.2

```
<table border=0 bgcolor=#000000 cellspacing=1 width="100%"
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>1.2</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2.1</td>
    <td>2.2</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3.1</td>
    <td>3.2</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4.1</td>
    <td>4.2</td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
sock = urllib.urlopen("someurl")

htmlread = sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlread)


tabledata = soup.find("table", {"border":"0", "bgcolor":"#000000", "cellspacing":"1", "width":"100%"})
other = tabledata.findAll("tr", {"bgcolor":"#FFFFFF"})

print other
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to find the last `tr` element and print all `td` text values inside it. First, to find the last `tr`, you can select all `tr` elements and then use `-1` to find the last one:

```
>>> last_tr = soup('tr')[-1]
```

Then, to find all `<td>` tags in that `<tr>` element:

```
>>> [td.text for td in last_tr('td')]
[u'4', u'4.1', u'4.2']
```

Comment: Hi. Is this a solution to the questioner's problem? if so - can you please add a bit more about how this solves their problem? Don't forget that total n00bs will google and possibly find this question/answer... If it's not a solution - it should probably be a comment :)

Comment: I usually post code first, then flesh it out. I got pulled away :) Updated.

Comment: :) It hit the "low quality post" review queue ;)

Answer (score 1):

Find all `td` elements inside the last `tr` element of the table:

```
table = soup.find("table", {"border":"0", "bgcolor":"#000000", "cellspacing":"1", "width":"100%"})
print [td.text for td in table.find_all('tr')[-1].find_all('td')]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <table border=0 bgcolor=#000000 cellspacing=1 width="100%"
... <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
...     <td>1</td>
...     <td>1.1</td>
...     <td>1.2</td>
... </tr>
... <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
...     <td>2</td>
...     <td>2.1</td>
...     <td>2.2</td>
... </tr>
... <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
...     <td>3</td>
...     <td>3.1</td>
...     <td>3.2</td>
... </tr>
... <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
...     <td>4</td>
...     <td>4.1</td>
...     <td>4.2</td>
... </tr>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> table = soup.find("table", {"border":"0", "bgcolor":"#000000", "cellspacing":"1", "width":"100%"})
>>> print [td.text for td in table.find_all('tr')[-1].find_all('td')]
[u'4', u'4.1', u'4.2']
```

Hope that helps.